# Pass interface slice in function and unmarshal into its items

Tags: go, parameters, interface, slice, unmarshalling

Can i pass into function a slice of structs, converted to `[]interface{}`, fill it and use after function end work?

Here is full example of the problem https://play.golang.org/p/iPijsawEEg

Short describe:

```
type DBResponse struct {
    Rows  int             `json:"rows"`
    Error string          `json:"error"`
    Value json.RawMessage `json:"value"`
}
type User struct {
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func loadDBRows(p []interface{}) {
    var response DBResponse
    someDataFromDB := []byte("{\"rows\":1, \"error\": \"\", \"value\": {\"name\":\"John\", \"id\":2}}")
    json.Unmarshal(someDataFromDB, &response)
    json.Unmarshal(response.Value, &p[0])
    fmt.Println(p)//p[0] filled with map, not object
}

func main() {
    users := make([]User, 5)
    data := make([]interface{}, 5)
    for i := range users {
        data[i] = users[i]
    }
    loadDBRows(data)
}
```

This problem can be easily solved for single `interface{}`, u can test in at full example. Why i can't solve it for slice?

I want to do it without reflect! Is there any "true way" to write universal json parser to selected data struct **without reflect and map[string]interface{}?** Don't want complicated code and extra operations

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `p` is a slice of interfaces, on this line `json.Unmarshal(response.Value, &p[0])` you're passing a pointer to an `interface{}` not to a `User` and since `json.Unmarshal` allows interfaces as the destination to which to unmarshal the data, it doesn't look under the `interface{}` for another type and just decodes the `json` into a `map`.

What you can do is to have the `interface{}` already be a pointer to a concrete type e.g. `data[i] = &users[i]` then you just pass the `interface{}` without `&` to `json.Unmarshal`.

```
func loadDBRows(p []interface{}) {
    var response DBResponse
    someDataFromDB := []byte("{\"rows\":1, \"error\": \"\", \"value\": {\"name\":\"John\", \"id\":2}}")
    json.Unmarshal(someDataFromDB, &response)
    json.Unmarshal(response.Value, p[0]) // notice the missing &
    fmt.Println(p)
}

users := make([]User, 5)
data := make([]interface{}, 5)
for i := range users {
    data[i] = &users[i] // notice the added &
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/GEbIq9febY

Comment: Thanks alot! I should read more about interface convertions, can you advice me a resource for it? Thanks again!

Comment: For `json.Unmarshal`'s conversion rules it's best to read the [golang docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) and to better understand what `interface{}`s are a good article can be found [here](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the reflect package to access the slice elements.

The function assumes that `p` is a slice:

```
func loadDBRows(p interface{}) {
  var response DBResponse
  someDataFromDB := []byte("{\"rows\":1, \"error\": \"\", \"value\": {\"name\":\"John\", \"id\":2}}")
  json.Unmarshal(someDataFromDB, &response)
  v := reflect.ValueOf(p). // get reflect.Value for argument
               Index(0).   // get first element assuming that p is a slice
               Addr().     // take address of the element
               Interface() // get the pointer to element as an interface{}
  json.Unmarshal(response.Value, v)
}
```

Use `loadDBRows` like this. There's no need to create the `[]interface{}` as in the question:

```
func main() {
  users := make([]User, 5)
  loadDBRows(users)
  fmt.Println(users)
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/YDDYajbx1y)